# ASP.Net MVC Popup Message after submit button clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC so I'm not completely sure that I have the model tied into the controller and view as it should be. I'm trying to have a message pop up after an error has occured. In this case the error occurs after the submit button has been clicked.

The view...

```
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert('@ViewBag.Message');

    });

</script>

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Guru Dental: Request Demo</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/flexslider/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/css/form-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/css/media-queries.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="~/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Top menu -->
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <br>
                <a href="http://www.gurudental.com/"><img class="logo-size" src="~/images/guru-dental-slogan.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'><br><br>Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")'><br><br>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Title -->
    <div class="page-title-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 wow fadeIn">
                    <h1>Demo Request</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Contact Us -->
    <div class="contact-us-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7 contact-form wow fadeInLeft">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("DemoSubmit", "CRM", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <h2>Rep Details</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-firstname">HSD Rep Code</label>
                            <input type="text" name="hsdrepcode" placeholder="Enter your HSD Rep code..." class="contact-name" id="contact-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-lastname">Rep First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="hsfirstname" placeholder="Enter your Rep first name..." class="contact-name" id="contact-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-lastname">Rep Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="hslastname" placeholder="Enter your Rep last name..." class="contact-name" id="contact-name">
                        </div>
                        <h2>Doctor Details</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-currentlocation">Doctor's First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your doctor's first name.." class="contact-subject" id="contact-subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-currentlocation">Doctor's Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter your doctor's last name..." class="contact-subject" id="contact-subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-currentlocation">Doctor's Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter your doctor's phone number..." class="contact-subject" id="contact-subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-currentlocation">Doctor's E-mail</label>
                            <input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Enter your doctor's e-mail..." class="contact-subject" id="contact-subject">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                    }
                </div>
```

The controller...

```
public ActionResult RequestDemo()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DemoSubmit(LeadInfo leadInfo)
{
    string salesEmail = CRMModels.GetNextSalesEmail();

    ViewBag.Message = CRMModels.AddLeadToCRM(leadInfo);

    if (ViewBag.Message == null)
    {
        EmailModels.SendEmailForLead(leadInfo, salesEmail);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
        return RequestDemo();
    }
}
```

The model...

```
if (hsdRepId != Guid.Empty)
{
    lead.Attributes["ree_hsdrepresentative"] = new EntityReference("ree_henryscheinrepresentative", hsdRepId);

    service.Create(lead);
}
else
{
    message = "Invalid HSD Representative Code";
}

return message;
```

In the DemoSubmit function, if there is a message to display, I need to go back to the view to display it. How do I do that? I tried to do with a redirect but that just gives me a new page with none of the data that was entered in and it didn't display the message.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code, in particular the fact you not binding any controls to you model so returning the view will always display empty controls. You should also include validation attributes on you properties to prevent posting and saving potentially bad data. Your view is also generating invalid html (lots of duplicate `id` attributes) and `<label>` tags which are not really labels (clicking on them wont set focus to the associated control because you don't associate them with a control.

Based on your view, your `LeadInfo` class looks something like (suggested attributes added)

```
public class LeadInfo
{
  [Display(Name = "HSD Rep code")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your HSD Rep code")]
  public string hsdrepcode { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Rep first name")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Rep first name")]
  public string hsfirstname { get; set; }
  .....
  [Display(Name = "Doctor's e-mail")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your doctor's e-mail")]
  [EmailAddress]
  public string emailaddress{ get; set; }   
}
```

You GET method should then be

```
public ActionResult RequestDemo()
{
  LeadInfo model = new LeadInfo();
  return View(model);
}
```

and the view should then strongly typed html helpers to bind to your properties and to display validation errors

```
@model LeadInfo
....
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true) // this is where you custom error message will be displayed

  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.hsdrepcode) // displays the text associated with the DisplayAttribute and is associated with the following textbox
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.hsdrepcode, new { placeholder="Enter your HSD Rep code...", @class="contact-name"})
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.hsdrepcode)
  ....
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
}
```

You should also include the following scripts (preferably using `@Scripts.Render()` and the bundling and minification features of MVC)

```
jquery-{version}.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

You should also be using layouts (master pages)

The post method is then

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RequestDemo(LeadInfo model) // not sure why you would change the name of the method?
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model); // return the view to fix any validation errors
  }
  string errorMessage = CRMModels.AddLeadToCRM(leadInfo);
  if (errorMessage == null)
  {
    string salesEmail = CRMModels.GetNextSalesEmail();
    EmailModels.SendEmailForLead(leadInfo, salesEmail);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
  else
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMessage);
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

Its not clear what the error message you want to return is, but you code suggests it might be associated with the `hsdrepcode` property, in which case, modify the code to associate the error with a particular property

```
ModelState.AddModelError("hsdrepcode", errorMessage);
```

Side note: Most of your code is ignoring the benefits of using MVC, to the point you may as well not use it. I recommend you go the the MVC site and work through the tutorials,

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I am in the process of going through a tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

On controller once you got error you can add error message to modalState

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid HSD Representative Code");
```

and to pop the error alert you can use html extension method to pop the message

```
public static HtmlString PopAlert(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string alertType = "danger",
    string heading = "")
{
    if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        return new HtmlString(string.Empty);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"alert alert-{0} alert-block\">", alertType);
    sb.Append("<button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>");

    if (!heading.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<h4 class=\"alert-heading\">{0}</h4>", heading);
    }

    sb.Append(htmlHelper.ValidationSummary());
    sb.Append("</div>");

    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

On view you simply call the Html extension method like this

```
 @Html.PopAlert()
```

hope this will help you :)